# Value not updating when form submitted(PHP, beginner level)

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, submit

Why does this form not update the values that the items in my session? The session seems to keep track of the value fine, before the form tries to allow users to edit the value. Here's what I wrote out  form submit:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        foreach($_POST['quantity'] as $key => $val) {

            if($val==0) {
                unset($_SESSION['Cart'][$key]);

            }else{
                $_SESSION['Cart'][$key]['quantity']=$val;
            }

        }


    }

?>
```

And here's the form:

```
<?php

            $sql="SELECT * FROM products where Product_ID IN (";

                    foreach($_SESSION['Cart'] as $id => $value){

                        $sql.=$id.",";
                        }
                        $sql=substr($sql, 0, -1).") ORDER BY Category ASC";
                        $query=mysql_query($sql);
                        $totalquantity=0;
                        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                            $subtotal=$_SESSION['Cart'][$row['Product_ID']['quantity']]['quantity'];
                            $totalquantity+=$subtotal;
                        ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $row['Name'] ?></td>
                                <td><input = type="text" name="Quantity [<?php echo $row['Product_ID'] ?>]" size="5" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['Cart'][$row['Product_ID']['quantity']]['quantity'] ?>"/> </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php
                        }


            ?>
```

And of course, the submit button is just

```
<button type="Submit" name="Submit">Update selection</button>
```

It looks like it should all work out properly, but it doesn't update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submit should be "submit" most probably.Change it either in the input filed or in the $_POST["Submit"]

Comment: Ah, that _possibly_ fixed it since now I'm being told that I have an Invalid argument supplied for foreach() and Undefined index: Quantity both in line 5 instead of the page updating without changing values. Now I guess I can move on to troubleshoot why I'm getting that, seems like the argument is okay, but guess I messed up somewhere.